# PL/SQL Developer - ORA-28041 authentication protocol internal error

Tags: oracle, plsqldeveloper

When I try change expired password in PL/SQL Developer 10.0 i receive error ORA-28041 authentication protocol internal error. Maybe someone of you know solutions for this?

Thanks.